# UpdateSourceTrigger / Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0

In the MSDN documentation, it documents that you can set the UpdateSourceTrigger to an event of your choosing...

[MSDN UpdateSourceTrigger Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx)

I can't seem to get this to work in Silverlight, as it is seems to want either Explicit or Default...

If this is only for WPF - how can you tell from the documentation that Silverlight is excluded?

Comment: This is the Silverlight Documentation page for the UpdateSourceTrigger Property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UpdateSourceTrigger is not an event, but an enumeration.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

So, what you are seeing are the choices available to Silverlight.

Comment: Ok so I have an UpdateSourceTrigger property that takes an enumeration of UpdateSourceTrigger - why does not Silverlight show the enumeration values of: PropertyChanged and LostFocus?    Likely these are not in the Silverlight CLR - but my question is how can you tell?

Comment: Here's the Silverlight page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight 5 adds support for PropertyChanged for UpdateSourceTrigger. You can find an example [here](http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2011/09/ngtweet-part-11-silverlight-5.html).